# New Application Template, how to set is as default?

Tags: template

I would like to transform my [BlenderFDS addon](https://blenderfds.org) into an Application Template to facilitate the UI customization.

I have read and tried that with command-line arguments you can setup a launcher that opens Blender with a specific app template:

> blender --app-template my_template

But is it possible to set the new Application Template as **default** when Blender starts without having to request to the users to set up a launcher?

Comment: There is a cryptic line in the [Application Templates](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html) _If you would like to keep the current application template active on restarting Blender, save your preferences._  I think this means that saving preferences with a new app template in place makes it the default but I haven't had time to test it.

Comment: I tried that with no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Alas, no.  Best I can come up with is the hack of setting up a command line script that adds the `--app-template my_template` argument to the command line and then calls Blender with the modified command line.  Make it an alias for "blender" on Un*x-like systems or a shortcut on WIndows.  Not foolproof but hits the 80/20 rule.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your suggestions. I think this is a missing feature that hinders the possibility of using application templates. At least the add-ons when enabled stay enabled.

Comment: I'm going to open an issue for that.

Comment: Here is the request for enhancement:
https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/JNQJ/?sorting=hot

Comment: Thanks for writing it up.  I agree with you.